# Guide to Learn J2ME

Tags: java, java-me, resources

I am starting study java2me. But I have some source study about it like ebook, source sample code, and . Could anybody give some link website or source ebook study about it.

Comment: Try [J2ME site](http://java.sun.com/javame/index.jsp)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Great Tutorials/articles from sun:

[Wireless Development Tutorial Part I](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/midp/articles/wtoolkit/)

> SUMMARY:This article contains
>   everything you need to know to get
>   started developing in the Java
>   Platform, Micro Edition (Java ME)
>   environment.

[J2ME Tutorial](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2005/02/09/j2me1.html)

> SUMMARY:What is J2ME? Cut away the
>   hype and the excess fat and you are
>   left with yet another (set of) Java
>   APIs. Since these APIs cannot run on a
>   traditional Java Virtual Machine
>   (JVM), due to the limited size of
>   mobile devices in regards to memory
>   and resource availability, J2ME
>   defines a limited version of the JVM
>   as well.

Comment: Hi adatapost, I want to design mobile interface that contain textbox and list of word in one form. But I don't know how to design it. Could you help me to that? I saw many dictionary in mobile they can put like that. Thanks, Sopolin

Answer (score 1):

A book called [J2ME Game Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1592001181). This is the book I have enjoyed the most and recommend to everybody

Answer (score 0):

I suggest having a look at LWUIT. http://lwuit.java.net/

Answer (score 0):

I found good articles(with their documents) in [samsung](http://innovator.samsungmobile.com/platform.main.do?platformId=3&nacode=uk).Although this may not be for beginners.

Answer (score -1):

My friends who happen to be J2ME developers always cite [http://19-2.168.0.1](http://compnetworking.about.com/od/routers/g/192_168_0_1_def.htm) as a reference.
They also seem to like guiding everyone to the first results of google when being asked for a "J2ME TUTORIAL".
Fortunately, the first two google results are also the first stackoverflow result.

Also, try the J2ME site: http://java.sun.com/javame/index.jsp